Broken graphics on imac 2008 Radeon after a tweak (not suspend issue)
I successfully got ubuntu 22.04 on my old iMac 20" early 2008 with ATI Radeon 2600xt/2700 card (RV630/M76). I can live with never suspending the system, which breaks the graphics, but after a period of not using it, I forgot the brightness control lived in upper right corner menu and foolishly installed some brightness control from some other thread and of course it broke mine on re-start. I'm doing a clean install alongside my old one to see if I can retrace the exact steps of what I did but in the meantime was hoping to ask here how to log in with either safe graphics or somehow revert to previous install.
Pardon the newbie mistake and question; happy to read another thread with common sense approach to such questions, but just an old fart trying to keep old systems going and still on steep end of learning curve. thanks in advance

so I think the command I may have added was changing the acpi backlight to vendor.
You can change the ACPI backlight brightness control to vendor in Ubuntu by modifying the kernel boot parameters.

Open a terminal window and edit the /etc/default/grub file using a text editor like nano with sudoedit /etc/default/grub

Locate the line that starts with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. This line defines the kernel parameters passed during boot.  At the end of this line, add the following parameter with a space character to separate the parameter from the rest of the line: acpi_backlight=vendor

Save the changes to the /etc/default/grub file. Then update the  changes that you made to the GRUB configuration with sudo update-grub

Reboot with sudo reboot


After the rebooting your system should use the vendor's backlight control method, potentially allowing brightness adjustment by pressing the function keys.

I edited the question by adding additional information about acpi_backlight=vendor . Please review my edit and correct it if necessary.
